# get exact time of a transaction in the past (not in mempool)

Tags: transactions, time

I am trying to build a python program, that returns details of a transaction, such as inputs, outputs, time, amount, etc. I have already loaded bitcoind -txindex, yet, when I decode a raw transaction, I do not get the time field. I have already read that decoderawtransaction does not contain the time of the transaction, but I am curious of the way btc explorers get those data?

The only time fields that I have found are in getblock command and in getrawmempool/getmempoolentry (although I do not focus on unconfirmed transaction). Can i get any info from them?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: pretty sure that doesn't really exist... block explorers probably write the time to an external DB the moment they receive a transaction on their node(s)

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, there are no time fields in transaction data.

Blocks have a timestamp but that can be up to 2 hours out.

Nodes can of course choose to record the time at which they first saw a transaction, this might be during relaying of transactions before the transaction is confirmed by being added to a block by a miner.